# Error : the data and reference values must have exactly the same levels in R

Tags: r

to get an idea about confussionMatrix() i tried like this

```
library(caret)
dataset1 = data.frame(forecast=c(4671397.7147,4602397.5887,4756124.2292,4754702.5180,4811885.2432,4886686.7732))

dataset2 = data.frame(PaidAmount= c(3377420.5946,3304701.4007,4197240.7709,3202655.9895,3332027.0383,3850655.8740))

result = confusionMatrix(dataset1$forecast,dataset2$PaidAmount)
print(result)
```

but i get an error

```
Error : the data and reference values must have exactly the same levels
```

[demo work here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=q5QrDMY9&version=1)

how can i solve this??

Comment: The confusion matrix is meant to be used with categorical data to measure frequencies between two variables. You have continuous data and hence the error.

Comment: ok, then how can i transform these values into categorical?

Comment: split them in bins (which will be categorical) and then use a confusion matrix. `as.character` changes a number to character (and i.e. converts to categorical) but I dont think this will be useful in your analysis here.

Comment: ok i wil try and let u know. anyway thanks for your valuable info